# Google Line Chart with Javascript literal Datatablse now showing X-Axis

Tags: google-visualization

I am implementing a Google (line) Chart based on a DataTable so I can change the type of graph 'on the fly'. I have successfully generated the data table (generated by script) based on https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

And implemented in an HTML Page (for testing purpose the page is empty so there is no interference with any other script/content)

The Y-axis, Legenda and lines are correctly generated, yet the x-axis appears to be missing.

**I am using the following content for the data table:**

```
{"cols":[{"id":"timestamp","label":"timestamp","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"sy","label":"sy","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"us","label":"us","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"average_cpu","label":"average_cpu","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"1372249356","f":""},{"v":0,"f":""},{"v":4,"f":""},{"v":43,"f":""}]},{"c":[{"v":"1372249650","f":""},{"v":13,"f":""},{"v":46,"f":""},{"v":49,"f":""}]},{"c":[{"v":"1372249950","f":""},{"v":4,"f":""},{"v":45,"f":""},{"v":47,"f":""}]},{"c":[{"v":"1372250250","f":""},{"v":2,"f":""},{"v":19,"f":""},{"v":46,"f":""}]},{"c":[{"v":"1372250550","f":""},{"v":3,"f":""},{"v":46,"f":""},{"v":51,"f":""}]}]}
```

**This all comes together in the following Javascript**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
    google.setOnLoadCallback(draw_15a6f1d2a7556b357de0d315596aa96c);
    function draw_15a6f1d2a7556b357de0d315596aa96c() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({"cols":[{"id":"timestamp","label":"timestamp","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"sy","label":"sy","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"us","label":"us","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"average_cpu","label":"average_cpu","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"1372249356","f":""},{"v":0,"f":""},{"v":4,"f":""},{"v":43,"f":""}]},{"c":[{"v":"1372249650","f":""},{"v":13,"f":""},{"v":46,"f":""},{"v":49,"f":""}]},{"c":[{"v":"1372249950","f":""},{"v":4,"f":""},{"v":45,"f":""},{"v":47,"f":""}]},{"c":[{"v":"1372250250","f":""},{"v":2,"f":""},{"v":19,"f":""},{"v":46,"f":""}]},{"c":[{"v":"1372250550","f":""},{"v":3,"f":""},{"v":46,"f":""},{"v":51,"f":""}]}]});
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('draw_15a6f1d2a7556b357de0d315596aa96c'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 800, height: 600});
    }
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="draw_15a6f1d2a7556b357de0d315596aa96c"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Yet I have no idea why the X-axis is not showing up. I have looked into the DataTable Roles but could not find a reference to show the X-axis
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles?hl=ja#jsonliteral
Nor does the LineChart documentation say which additional arguments have to be supplied.

jsfiddle.net/WuLWF/ (When breaking it up in pieces according to Fiddle standard it did not work)

Or perhaps my DataTable is wrong generated.

Please guide me in the correct direction, 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x-axis is showing up but the labels are not showing up.  Your first column is of type string, so you wouldn't see gridlines in any case, but for each row, the first column "f" property is an empty string, which means it will be displayed in the axis label as an empty string, just as it does.

I bet you did this so the tooltips would not show these same values.   You might want to investigate custom tooltips to display whatever you want in the tooltips.

If you had used numbers instead of strings for the first column, then the axis labels would be generated and displayed as numbers, using the axis format option, and the values might happen to be close to the same values as in your first column.  Discrete string values are used as is.

Or perhaps you would prefer to use a type of date, datetime, or timeofday.  These are also treated as continuous, like numbers, rather than discrete, so the formatting of the tick labels is determined by the axis format option.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I needed to fill in the f value in order to display the X-axis for Strings. Thanks, this was really help full!